# Replace Unified compouse unicode for Google unique unicode

Tags: android, regex, unicode

I need to replace the Unified composed unicodes (They are Keycaps from 0 to 9 and country flags).

Actually im implementing Emojis for my android application, then, i need to convert the Unified compouse unicode for the Google unicode, like this:

For the Keycap 0, the compused unicodes are `\u00300-\u20E3` and google single unicode its `U+FE837` . I have the regex for find unicode compoused (only for keycaps number), its this:

```
[\u0030-\u20E3]
```

Because keycaps unicode goes from tange \u00300 to \u00309. Then, there are any way to convert it with regex to the google unicode equivalence? Or you know other way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: [U+FE837 is not a valid Unicode character](http://www.charbase.com/FE837-unicode-invalid-character). You could try escaping it as shown on the linked page.

Comment: And why android change that unicode for an emoji?